# Proof of linear independence for vectors

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors

> If vectors $x_1,...x_n$ are linearly independent vectors over a vector space $V$, prove that vectors
> $$x_1,x_1+x_2,..., x_1 + x_2 + ... +x_n$$
> are linearly independent as well.

So what I know is that linear independence means that, say for $x_1$ and $x_2$:
$$\begin{align}&\alpha x_1+\beta x_2 = 0  \\ \Rightarrow \space& \alpha = \beta = 0\end{align}$$

With this I know that $x_1$ and $x_2$ are linearly independent. Continuing by the same logic:

$$\begin{align}&\alpha x_1+\beta x_2 + \gamma x_3 = 0  \\ \Rightarrow \space& 0 + \gamma x_3 = 0\\ \space& x_3 \ne 0\\ \Rightarrow \space& \alpha = \beta = \gamma = 0\end{align}$$

I could continue doing this over and over. My problem is how do I write a "general" solution down as an answer. How would I write it mathematically as a proof.

Comment: Use mathematical induction.

Comment: You can also write those vectors as the result of a matrix operation on the originals, and show that the matrix has full rank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple problems with your attempt. First, you don't seem to prove that the vectors $x_1, x_1 + x_2, x_1+x_2+x_3$ are linearly independent. Instead, you prove that $x_1, x_2, x_3$ are linearly independent - but we assumed that they are, so there's no use in proving this! Second, from $\alpha x_1 + \beta x_2 + \gamma x_3 = 0$ we cannot deduce $\alpha x_1 + \beta x_2 = 0$, so we cannot use the fact that $x_1$ and $x_2$ are linearly independent in the way you seem to try to.

Instead, you can work from the definitions. To prove that the vectors $x_1,x_1+x_2,..., x_1 + x_2 + ... +x_n$ are linearly independent, we have to show that whenever
$$ \alpha_1 x_1 + \alpha_2 (x_1 + x_2) + \dots + \alpha_n (x_1 + \dots + x_n) = 0, $$
we have $\alpha_1 = \dots = \alpha_n = 0$. Rearranging the above equality we have
$$
(\alpha_1 + \alpha_2 + \dots + \alpha_n) x_1 + (\alpha_2 + \dots + \alpha_n) x_2 + \dots + \alpha_n x_n = 0.
$$
Now the fact that $x_1,\dots,x_n$ are linearly independent gives us that
$$\alpha_1 + \alpha_2 + \dots + \alpha_n = \alpha_2 + \dots + \alpha_n = \dots = \alpha_n = 0.$$

Now we just have to show that this implies $\alpha_1 = \dots = \alpha_n = 0$, but this is easy by working backwards: $\alpha_n = 0$ is given, so that $0 = \alpha_{n-1} + \alpha_n = \alpha_{n-1}$, so that $0 = \alpha_{n-2} + \alpha_{n-1} + \alpha_n = \alpha_{n-2}$ ... etc. (You can streamline this argument by using induction on $n$, as suggested in the comments.)